# liquibase failOnError:false runAlways:false not working

Tags: java, liquibase, liquibase-sql

It's possible not to run again an SQL file which fails in the past with liquibase?
I tried with failOnError:false runAlways:false but no DATABASECHANGELOG entry is made.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks and with

```
--preconditions onFail:MARK_RAN
```

it's working like I want